# Making only admins execute commands

Tags: discord

The problem is that I couldn't figure out a way to make this command only accessible by admins. I've tried using if statements, however, I failed. message. I am not sure if **member. roles. cache. has( ' 732524984777572363 ' )** would allow members with the role ID 732524984777572363 to execute it since there's already an if statement.

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const cooldown = new Set();

module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args, config) => {
    if(cooldown.has(msg.author.id)) {
        msg.reply(`You need to wait ${config.COOLDOWN} minutes to use this command again!`)
            .then((m) => {
                msg.delete();

                setTimeout(() => {
                    m.delete();
                }, 5000);
            });
    } else {
        fs.readFile('./accounts/crunchy.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;

            data = data + '';
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            let account = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)];

            fs.writeFile('./accounts/crunchy.txt', lines.slice(1).join('\n'), function(err) {
                if(err) throw err;
            });

            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .addField('Rate Us Here | قيمنا هنا ', `<#915***********80>`)
            .addField('CrunchyRoll Account',`\n**${account}**`)
            .setThumbnail('**************************')
            .setColor("#363940")
            .setFooter('Bot made by ******')
            .setTimestamp();

            msg.author.send(embed);

            msg.reply('I\'ve sent you the account! Please check your DM!')
                .then(m => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        m.delete();
                    }, 900000);
                });

            cooldown.add(msg.author.id);
            setTimeout(() => {
                cooldown.delete(msg.author.id);
            }, config.COOLDOWN * 60 * 1000);
        });
    }
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: `CrunchyRoll`,
    description: `Sends you a CrunchyRoll account!`
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a role check and a server check will prevent any issues!

The first line would be:

```js
if(!msg.guild) return;
```

This line makes sure the user is running the command in a server(guild), this prevents a member role from being undefined or null.

The second line would be:

```js
if(!msg.author.roles.cache.has('ROLE_ID_HERE')) return;
```

This prevents a user from running a command if they do not have a specific role.

The final code would be:

```js
if(!msg.guild) return;
if(!msg.author.roles.cache.has('ROLE_ID_HERE')) return;
```

You will need to add this to the top of your code in order for it to work as you'd like.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const cooldown = new Set();

module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args, config) => {
    if(!msg.guild) return;
    if(!msg.member.roles.cache.has('ROLE_ID_HERE')) return;
    if(cooldown.has(msg.author.id)) {
        msg.reply(`You need to wait ${config.COOLDOWN} minutes to use this command again!`)
            .then((m) => {
                msg.delete();

                setTimeout(() => {
                    m.delete();
                }, 5000);
            });
    } else {
        fs.readFile('./accounts/crunchy.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;

            data = data + '';
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            let account = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)];

            fs.writeFile('./accounts/crunchy.txt', lines.slice(1).join('\n'), function(err) {
                if(err) throw err;
            });

            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .addField('Rate Us Here | قيمنا هنا ', `<#915***********80>`)
            .addField('CrunchyRoll Account',`\n**${account}**`)
            .setThumbnail('**************************')
            .setColor("#363940")
            .setFooter('Bot made by ******')
            .setTimestamp();

            msg.author.send(embed);

            msg.reply('I\'ve sent you the account! Please check your DM!')
                .then(m => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        m.delete();
                    }, 900000);
                });

            cooldown.add(msg.author.id);
            setTimeout(() => {
                cooldown.delete(msg.author.id);
            }, config.COOLDOWN * 60 * 1000);
        });
    }
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: `CrunchyRoll`,
    description: `Sends you a CrunchyRoll account!`
};
```

Comment: It looks good, but unfortunately, it didn't work. Members were still able to use that command.

Comment: Sorry, just a small confusion over the code, I realised that your code uses `msg` and not `message`.

Comment: Also changed msg.author to msg.member as message.author is a discord user while msg.member is a discord member.